# MySQL - How to Count registers in a Date based on a DATETIME field

Tags: mysql, count

I Have a table with:

```
CODEID | USERNAME | SENDTIME
94849  | John     | 2017-09-14 15:35:04
84749  | John     | 2017-09-14 15:24:21
83998  | Mike     | 2017-09-14 12:16:16
28399  | Anna     | 2017-09-13 22:15:24
11234  | Paul     | 2017-09-13 19:21:22
49489  | John     | 2017-09-12 08:15:02
```

I need this:

```
DATE       |   CODEID_TOTAL
2017-09-14 |       3
2017-09-13 |       2
2017-09-12 |       1
```

I need a solution to count all CODEID sent by day.

tks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use count( distinct CODEID  ) and group by

```
select date(sendtime) ,  count(distinct CODEID) CODEID_TOTAL
from my_table
group by date(sendtime)
```

Comment: Tks scaisEdge.. I don't know a lot of SQL but  I know this is a simply question for SQL experts.. :D - Works Greaaaaat to me!! Save my day! tks a lottt!!